# A word for someone (or something?) that is totally different from how they (or it) appear?

Tags: british-english

I'm looking for a word to describe someone who is totally different to the impression they give? It is actually one of my son's teachers whom I am looking to describe. He comes across very gruff and tough, but in actuality is one of the kindest teachers in the school. 
Thanks :)

Comment: possible dupe of: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/349261/word-for-something-which-isnt-what-it-seems-to-be?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a dupe, but you could describe the behaviour, rather than the person, as "deceptive".  This doesn't carry any negative connotations.  Eg "His gruffness was deceptive - he was actually one of the kindest teachers in the school".

Comment: Not generic in the sense of your title, but [*cold hands, warm heart*](http://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/cold-hands-warm-heart) can have the sense of the specific example you give (gruff but kind).